# Обработка блокировки Button, если несколько EditText пустые

Tags: java, android, activity, android-edittext

На Activity есть 6 полей RememberEditText и Button, для перехода на следующий Activity. Как заблокировать эту кнопку, если пусто хотя бы одно поле ввода?

Код Activity1:

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

RememberEditText cel, kr1, kr2, kr3, alt1, alt2;
Button postrresh, sbrosierarh;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    cel = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
    kr1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr1);
    kr2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr2);
    kr3 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr3);
    alt1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.alt1);
    alt2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.alt2);
    postrresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postrresh);

    postrresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(Activity1.this, MessageActivity1.class);
            intent4.putExtra("message1", cel.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message2", kr1.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message3", kr2.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message4", kr3.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message5", alt1.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message6", alt2.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent4);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант покороче:

```
public class Activity1  extends AppCompatActivity {

    RememberEditText cel, kr1, kr2, kr3, alt1, alt2;
    Button postrresh;
    private Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        cel = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
        kr1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr1);
        kr2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr2);
        kr3 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr3);
        alt1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.alt1);
        alt2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.alt2);
        postrresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postrresh);
        addTextWatcher(cel);
        addTextWatcher(kr1);
        addTextWatcher(kr2);
        addTextWatcher(kr3);
        addTextWatcher(alt1);
        addTextWatcher(alt2);
        postrresh.setEnabled(ids.isEmpty());
        //...
    }

    private void addTextWatcher(final RememberEditText edit) {
        edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() == 0)
                    ids.add(edit.getId());
                else
                    ids.remove(edit.getId());
                postrresh.setEnabled(ids.isEmpty());
            }
        });
        // название класса `RememberEditText` наталкивает на мысль, 
        // что текст в нем как-то сам будет восстанавливаться 
        // по каким-то одному ему известным алгоритмам и не факт, 
        // что это произойдет после назначения обработчиков 
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText()))
            ids.add(edit.getId());
    }
}
```

А вообще данные должны быть в модели, а editText'ы нужны только для редактирования. Что если понадобится дополнительная валидация ввода (емейлы, телефоны и т.д.), а потом еще и в других местах приложения?.. В общем суррогат модели - ids надо оформить объектом и научить его валидировать себя (или это будет валидатор, валидирующий модель).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так, пример для одного поля ввода

```
cel.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() == 0){
        postrresh.setEnabled(false);
      }else{
        postrresh.setEnabled(true);
      }
    }
  });
```

**update**

Воспроизвел ситуацию. Если просто на каждое поле ввода установить слушатель как представлено выше задача не решается. Есть мнение реализовать следующим образом.
Создать метод в `Activity`, который будет возвращать `false` если хоть одно поле ввода пустое.

```
private boolean isAllEditWithText(){

    return (editText1.getText().length() != 0
            && editText2.getText().length() != 0
            && editText3.getText().length() != 0
            && editText4.getText().length() != 0
            && editText5.getText().length() != 0
            && editText6.getText().length() != 0);
}
```

После связывания кнопки (в `onCreate`) установить включен/выключен результатом возвращаемым этим методом. *(Вдруг появится желание заполнять поля по умолчанию.)*

```
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button.setEnabled(isAllEditWithText());
```

В слушателях на каждое поле ввода тоже вызывать этот метод.

```
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            button.setEnabled(isAllEditWithText());
        }
    });
```

Так работает. Кнопка будет выключена если хоть в одном поле ввода длина содержимого равна 0.

Comment: это не будет работать, потому что проверка будет выполнена только один раз во время выполнения, как правило `onCreate()` и весь последующий ввод будет проигнорирован. Нужно на колбэки самих полей ввода вешать проверки и пока они все не "отметятся", что не пустые, кнопку не разблокировать.

Comment: у меня как раз и не работало, я пытался так написать..

Comment: @pavlofff: изменил, спасибо

Comment: @Sir..: изменил ответ

Comment: @pavlofff: опять же не то, по моему, нет? при пустых других один слушатель будет включать кнопку

Comment: скомпилировал,  для одного поля работает, по крайней мере

Comment: условие проверки слишком низкопроизводительное, не забывайте, что оно будет вызываться при каждом нажатии буквы. Достаточно оптимальный алгоритм я написал в своем ответе

Comment: @pavlofff: на каждую букву да, но по моему не так страшно запрашивать длину с 6 полей. Есть задачи куда затратнее. Конечно же улучшать можно и нужно. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для трех полей примерно так (больше мне писать лень). Кнопка `postrresh` должна быть в разметке установлена в неактивное состояние:

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

  RememberEditText kr1, kr2, kr3;
  Button postrresh;
  boolean setBool[] = new setBool[3] ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        kr1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr1);
        kr2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr2);
        kr3 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr3);
        postrresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postrresh);

        kr1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           @Override    
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

           @Override    
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              setButtonEnabled((s.length() != 0), 0); // 0 - индекс в массиве
           });

        kr2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           @Override    
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

           @Override    
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              setButtonEnabled((s.length() != 0), 1); // 1 - индекс в массиве
           });

        kr3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           @Override    
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

           @Override    
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              setButtonEnabled((s.length() != 0), 2); // 2- индекс в массиве
           });

        postrresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              ...
            }
        });
    }

     void setButtonEnabled( boolean bool, int index){

         setBool[index] = bool; // запоминаем текущее состояние для каждого поля ввода
         postrresh.setEnabled(isAllTrue(setBool); // устанавливаем активность кнопки по текущему состоянию

     }

     boolean isAllTrue(boolean[] array) {

          // если в массиве все `true`, то вернет `true` иначе `false`
          for(boolean b : array) if(!b) return false; //если какой то не true, нет смысла продолжать весь цикл
     return true;
     }
}
```

Логика основана на том, что при каждом вводе в любое из полей в поле класса записываем текущее состояние (пустое оно или нет) и по состоянию всего массива состояний устанавливаем активность кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Проверка валидации

```
private boolean validateForm(){

    boolean valid = true;
name = editTextname.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || name.length() < 3){
        editTextname.setError("required field");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        editTextname.setError(null);
    }

    surname = editTextsurname.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(surname)){
        editTextsurname.setError("required field");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        editTextsurname.setError(null);
    }
```

прочие условия ставьте свои. Далее в `onClick`

```
 if (!validateForm()){
                return;
            } else {
```

"иначе" переход в  Ваш активити. В `validateForm()` сколько угодно пихайте Эдит текстов и условий для них. Если хоть одно не пройдет, пользователь не перейдет в активити. + нужный для исправления эдит текст будет помечен

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    cel = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
    kr1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr1);
    kr2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr2);
    kr3 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr3);
    alt1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.alt1);
    alt2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.alt2);
    postrresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postrresh);

    postrresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
if intent4.putExtra("message1", cel.getText().toString().lenght==0)return;
if  intent4.putExtra("message2", kr1.getText().toString()).lenght==0)return;
if intent4.putExtra("message3", kr2.getText().toString()).lenght==0)return;
if intent4.putExtra("message4", kr3.getText().toString()).lenght==0)return;
if intent4.putExtra("message5", alt1.getText().toString()).lenght==0)return;
if intent4.putExtra("message6", alt2.getText().toString()).lenght==0)return;
Intent intent4 = new Intent(Activity1.this, MessageActivity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
}}
```

попробуйте этот код