# Где и как мне разместить проверку на пустоту моего EditText в android приложении?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня в приложении есть экран входа, где находится кнопка и два `EditText` для пароля и логина. Вот у меня возник вопрос - как и где нужно разместить проверку на заполненность этих двух полей для ввода. Вот у меня есть функция `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        sp = getSharedPreferences("language", 0);
        String lang = sp.getString("language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(
                config,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        );
        setContentView(activity_login);

        submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        CheckBox user = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        user.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });


        sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, 0);
        final boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
        user.setChecked(hasVisited);

        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);


        if (hasVisited) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        } else {
            try {


                submitBtn.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.button));

                submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        sendPost();
                    }
                });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                        SendLogcatMail(ex);
                    }
                });


            }
        }


    }
```

и есть функция которая отправляет запрос на сервер, и мне неохота ганять сервер почем зря. И вот я не могу понять где мне именно разместить эту проверку:

```
if (titleEt.getText().toString().equals("") || bodyEt.getText().toString().equals("")) {
} else {
}
```

это один тип проверки, есть конечно еще один, который проверяет длину, но суть не важна, я не могу понять где его разместить. Пробовал в `onCreate()` но у меня тогда кнопка вообще не работает, если например ставить если поле не заполнено то тогда кнопка неактивна. Либо можно закинуть эту проверку в функцию которая отправляет запрос, но нужно сделать эту проверку до отправка запроса, чтобы на сервер не приходили пустые строки, конечно у него тоже есть проверка и все такое, но какой смысл если можно все это делать на стороне клиента. Надеюсь я не первый кто задумался над этим вопросом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778826/177345

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно просто сделать некликабельной кнопку отправки запроса при невыполнении условия.

Проще всего это сделать в реактивном стиле. Можно взять либу [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) и сделать так (код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)):

```
sendButton.enable = false
Flowable.combineLatest(
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText1),
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText2),
    { (text1: String, text2: String) -> text1.isNotEmpty() && text2.isNotEmpty() }
).subscribe(sendButton::enable)
```

код на [java](/questions/tagged/java)

```
sendButton.setEnabled(false);
Flowable.combineLatest(
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText1),
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText2),
    (String text1, String text2) -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(text1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(text2)
).subscribe(sendButton::enable)
```

Comment: а на java никак нельзя сделать? а то я с котлином не очень дружу)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko а это на перспективу :) по красоте же написано, а так придется юзать то, что снизу :(

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, добавил вариант для `java`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб isNotEmpty :)

Comment: @iFr0z, вроде бы в `TextUtils` только `isEmpty` есть)

Comment: отбой ! не заметил

Answer (score 2):

**Если один EditText:**

```
[ваш злой edit].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.isNotEmpty()) {
           //initBtn с отправкой на сервер
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

});
```

---

**Если два EditText:**

```
[ваш злой edit1].addTextChangedListener(watcher);
[ваш злой edit2].addTextChangedListener(watcher);

submitBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.hashCode() == [ваш злой edit1].getText().hashCode() && 
            s.hashCode() == [ваш злой edit2].getText().hashCode() &&
            s.isNotEmpty()) { //проверка на пустоту у двух EditText сразу

            submitBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //initBtn с отправкой на сервер

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
};
```