# Android. Изменение цвета кнопки в зависимости от значений в других классах

Tags: android

Есть n(2-8, в зависимости от экрана) кастомных EditText. Они одинаковые по структуре, отличаются только логикой, поэтому опубликую один:

**EmailField**

```
public class EmailField extends AppCompatEditText {
    ...

    public EmailField(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTextWatcher(this);
    }

    public EmailField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTextWatcher(this);
    }

    public EmailField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setTextWatcher(this);
    }

    private void setTextWatcher(AppCompatEditText editText) {
        this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //Some logic
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //Some logic
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    public String getError() {
        //Some logic
        return error;
    }
}
```

Это поле для ввода email, которое на лету проверяет валидность данных и меняет цвет текста/гравитацию/иконки у поля в зависимости от успеха/провала проверки. Такое же поле есть для пароля, телефона, имени, ...; Сделано это было в основном для того чтобы растолкать тонну логики по отдельным классам.

На экране с этими полями присутствует функция `validation()`, которая срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку `Отправить данные`. Функция по очереди обращается к `getError()` каждого поля. `getError()` возвращает либо текст ошибки, либо `null`. `validation()` отправляет данные на сервер, если все поля вернули `null`.

Сейчас мне нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка автоматически, без пользовательского участия сама меняла цвет, если все поля заполнены корректно. То есть без вызова `validation()`. Я несколько в ступоре. Как лучше подойти к этой задаче?

Я так понимаю что нужно создать свой класс, унаследованный от Button и передавать ему все эти поля, чтобы как - то мониторить их состояние(правда пока неизвестно как).

Comment: Взялись минусить - пишите за что.

Comment: Ну вот и добавь в TextWatcher проверку и изменения цвета текста

Comment: Каким образом? Я могу передать в каждое из моих кастомных полей ссылку на кнопку. И могу менять цвет кнопки в `TextWatcher` в зависимости от состояния того поля, в которое я передал ссылку. Но мне нужно менять цвет кнопки в зависимости от состояния всех кастомных полей.

Comment: Сделай интерфейс в классе с кнопкой, обращайся к нему из других классов. В нем вызывай метод проверки полей

Comment: смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778826/177345), как выпонить действие в зависимости от содержимого нескольких EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал как посоветовал `Andrey Mihalev`. Не обломлюсь и пографоманю.

Моя реализация на примере класса `EmailField`(структура в вопросе), для тех кому предстоит страдать этим всем делом. Мб кому поможет. Сразу оговорюсь что я стажёр, возможно(и вероятнее всего) всё это можно сделать гораздо проще, но сделано как сделано, читать и юзать на свой страх и риск.

1) Создал интерфейс внутри класса(внутренний - чтобы не засорять пакеты кучей интерфейсов):

```
public interface EmailListener {
        void onEmailCorrect(boolean isEmailCorrect);
    }
```

2) Добавил в класс поле с этим интерфейсом:

`private EmailListener emailListener;`

3) Добавил метод, инициализирующий этот интерфейс. Этим методом будет пользоваться класс - кнопка, которая будет "мониторить" это поле.

```
public void setOnEmailListener(EmailListener listener) {
        emailListener = listener;
    }
```

4) Прописал в `onTextChanged` условия валидации - то есть условия, при котором наш интерфейс "возвращает"(не баньте =( ) `true` или `false`. На моём примере:

```
 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if (editText.getText() != null && Utility.isValidEmail(String.valueOf(editText.getText()))) {
     //Some logic: pic, text, etc...
     emailListener.onEmailCorrect(true); //!
     } 
     else {
     //Some logic: pic, text, etc...
     emailListener.onEmailCorrect(false); //!
             }
         }
```

5) Сделал свою кастомную "кнопку"(которая по факту `RelativeLayout`, но так надо лично мне. Вам от `Button` никто не помешает унаследоваться):

```
public class ButtonLayout extends RelativeLayout
```

Дальше начинается веселье.

6) Добавил в класс - кнопку карту, где ключ - это название класса, которое валидируется(`EmailField`), значение - корректность его заполнения(`true/false`).

```
 private HashMap<String, Boolean> fieldMap;
```

7) Добавил в класс - кнопку сеттер с двумя самописными методами:

```
public void setViews(View... views) {
        initMap(views);
        setListeners(views);
    }
```

Так я передаю кнопке список полей, которые она будет "мониторить". В целевой активити теперь можно написать:

```
 buttonAuthorizationSend.setViews(emailField, passwordField,//много других кастомных полей);
```

8) Дальше пишу метод `initMap()`:

```
private void initMap(View[] views) {
        fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (View currentView : views) {
            fieldMap.put(currentView.getClass().getSimpleName(), false);
        }
    }
```

Так я инициализирую мапу и заполняю её названиями классов наших полей.

9) Дальше пишу метод, который будет менять цвет кнопки тогда когда всем ключам в нашей мапе будет проставлен параметр `true`, иначе - будет возвращать её к дефолтному цвету:

```
private void changeLayoutBackgroundColor() {
        if (fieldMap.containsValue(false)) {
            this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.disable_buttom));
        } else {
            this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
    }
```

10) Пока нифига не работает. В `setViews()` был метод `setListeners`, теперь пишу его. Он главный и связующий между кастомными полями и "кнопкой". Этот метод берёт массив `View`, который я получил в `setViews`, пробегает по нему, определяет класс каждого `View` и вызывает свой, написанный индивидуально для каждого класса метод `set!className!Listener`:

```
private void setListeners(View[] viewArray) {
        for (View currentView : viewArray) {
            if (currentView instanceof EmailField) {
                setEmailListener((EmailField) currentView);
            } else if (currentView instanceof PasswordField) {
                setPasswordListener((PasswordField) currentView);
            } else if (currentView instanceof CodeField) {
                setCodeListener((CodeField) currentView);
            }
        }
    }
```

Осталось только написать эти методы. Каждый метод вешает на своё поле созданный внутри кастомного поля `Listener`(п.1), который мониторит как меняется переменная и обновляет значение в карте после каждого введённого символа(которое прежде обновляется в `onTextChanged`).

```
private void setEmailListener(EmailField emailField) {
        emailField.setOnEmailListener(isEmailCorrect -> {
            fieldMap.put("EmailField", isEmailCorrect);
            changeLayoutBackgroundColor();
        });
    }

    private void setPasswordListener(PasswordField passwordField) {
        passwordField.setOnPasswordListener(isPasswordCorrect -> {
            fieldMap.put("PasswordField", isPasswordCorrect);
            changeLayoutBackgroundColor();
        });
    }

    private void setCodeListener(CodeField codeField) {
        codeField.setOnCodeListener(isCodeCorrect -> {
            fieldMap.put("CodeField", isCodeCorrect);
            changeLayoutBackgroundColor();
        });
    }
```

Как - то так.

Answer (score 0):

Каждое поле в событии afterTextChanged() пусть вызывает Процедуру которая в свою очередь получает getError() от всех контролов и меняет их цвет ...