# Валидность веденных данных в DialogFragment

Tags: android

Реализую регистрацию с помощью Firebase. Данные для регистрации пользователь будет вводить в открывшейся DialogFragment.

```
public class DialogFragmentRegEmail extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
DialogFragmentRegEmailListener mListener;
public static  EditText sEtRegName;
public static EditText sEtRegEmail;
public static EditText sEtRegPassword;

public DialogFragmentRegEmail() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View rootView= getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_reg_email, null);
    sEtRegName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_register_name);
    sEtRegEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_register_email);
    sEtRegPassword = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_register_password);


    builder.setView(rootView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.sign_in, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    sEtRegName.getText().toString();
                    sEtRegEmail.getText().toString();
                    sEtRegPassword.getText().toString();
                    mListener.onDialogRegPositiveClick(DialogFragmentRegEmail.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    DialogFragmentRegEmail.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    mListener.onDialogRegNegativeClick(DialogFragmentRegEmail.this);
                }
            });


    return builder.create();
}



public interface DialogFragmentRegEmailListener {
    void onDialogRegPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    void onDialogRegNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        mListener = (DialogFragmentRegEmailListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement DialogFragmentRegEmailListener");
    }
}
```

}

dialog_fragment_reg_email.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_register_name"
        style="@style/dialog_register_edit_text"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_register_email"
        style="@style/dialog_register_edit_text"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_register_password"
        style="@style/dialog_register_edit_text"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Согласно документации раздуваю макет диалога, а кнопки устанавливаю программно.
Вопрос вот в чем - как осуществить проверку введенных данных в диалоге? Допустим если имя пользователя нулевое или пароль меньше 5 знаков и показывать предупреждение + если данные не подходят, то чтоб кнопка "Войти" была неактивна.
В примерах от гугла нашла [реализацию](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth/app/src/main)

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailField.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEmailField.setError(null);
    }

    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        mPasswordField.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mPasswordField.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Там данные проверяются уже при создании аккаунта и вводятся они в той же активити. У меня же данные приходят из фрагмента и наверное разумнее их там и проверять. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать.

```
public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener, DialogFragmentRegEmail.DialogFragmentRegEmailListener {
        @Override
    public void onDialogRegPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
      registerName = DialogFragmentRegEmail.sEtRegName.getText().toString();
        mDetailTextView.setText(registerName);


    }
```

Comment: Вы можете использовать TextWatcher для проверки валидности полей в реалтайме. Или же при нажатии на кнопку проверять данные и только потом отправлять. Где это проверять? Это зависит от реализации. Лучше если этим занимается презентер, но если вы пишете логику в активити и фрагментах то там же и проверяйте

Comment: смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778826/177345), как блокировать кнопку, пока данные в полях ввода не валидны (в том случае есть хоть одно незаполненное поле ввода, но проверки могут быть любые). так же есть множество готовых библиотек для [валидации](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+validation&type=)