# Помогите реализовать проверку заполненности полей

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onButtonClick (View v){

        EditText damage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleDamage);
        EditText fear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleFear);
        EditText health = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleHealth);
        EditText volya = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleVolya);
        EditText power = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.polePower);
        Button result = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResult);
        TextView resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poleResult);

        int dmg = Integer.parseInt(damage.getText().toString());
        int fr = Integer.parseInt(fear.getText().toString());
        int hlth = Integer.parseInt(health.getText().toString());
        int vl = Integer.parseInt(volya.getText().toString());
        int pwr = Integer.parseInt(power.getText().toString());
        int resMind = fr - vl;
        int resHealth = dmg - pwr;
        int resWin = hlth - pwr;

        resText.setText("Потеря рассудка: " + Integer.toString(resMind) + ", Потеря здоровья: " + Integer.toString(resHealth) + ", Остаток жизней у монстра: " + resWin);
        /*if (resWin <= 0){
            resText.setText("Победа !!!");
        }
        else
            resText.setText("Поражение, попробуйте сразиться еще");*/



    }
}
```

Как запретить нажатие кнопки если хотя бы одно из 5 полей не содержит значение?

Comment: Через переданный в onButtonClick -> view: v.setVisible(false). А у EditText есть метод getText. Далее, думаю, разберетесь.

Comment: Можно чуть подробней? не хватает мозгов чтоб применить Вашу подсказку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778826/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Выполнять поиск элементов каждый раз - плохой тон. определите глобальные переменные для класса и инициализируйте элементы интерфейса единожды в методе onCreate
2. Каждое строковое значение имеет метод isEmpty - оно помогает понять есть ли у него содержимое
3. Не советую блокировать кнопку пока не введен весь текст. Вы должны заранее об это уведомить пользователя иначе вы получите плохой пользовательский опыт: пользователь не сможет догадаться, что нужно, что бы кнопка разблокировалась. Лучше выполняйте проверку по каждому нажатию на кнопку и сообщайте пользователю, если он не заполнил все поля.
4. Использование слушателя изменения текста - плохой опыт. операция проверки и блокировки будет вызываться чаще, а значит тратить больше вычислительных ресурсов, нежели использование того метода, что я описал выше.

Используйте мой код ниже, как пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText txtDamage;
EditText txtFear;
EditText txtHealth;
EditText txtVolya;
EditText txtPower;
Button btnResult;
TextView lbResText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtDamage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleDamage);
    txtFear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleFear);
    txtHealth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleHealth);
    txtVolya = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poleVolya);
    txtPower = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.polePower);
    btnResult = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResult);
    lbResText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poleResult);

}

public void onButtonClick (View v){

    if(checkInputIsEmpty()) {
        showMessage("Ошибка", "Необходимо запонлить все поля");
        return;
    }

    int dmg = Integer.parseInt(txtDamage.getText().toString());
    int fr = Integer.parseInt(txtFear.getText().toString());
    int hlth = Integer.parseInt(txtHealth.getText().toString());
    int vl = Integer.parseInt(txtVolya.getText().toString());
    int pwr = Integer.parseInt(txtPower.getText().toString());
    int resMind = fr - vl;
    int resHealth = dmg - pwr;
    int resWin = hlth - pwr;

    lbResText.setText("Потеря рассудка: " + Integer.toString(resMind) + ", Потеря здоровья: " + Integer.toString(resHealth) + ", Остаток жизней у монстра: " + resWin);
    /*if (resWin <= 0){
        resText.setText("Победа !!!");
    }
    else
        resText.setText("Поражение, попробуйте сразиться еще");*/
}

private boolean checkInputIsEmpty() {
    return txtDamage.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
            txtFear.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
            txtHealth.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
            txtVolya.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
            txtPower.getText().toString().isEmpty();
}

private void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
    builder.create().show();
}
}
```

Comment: Жесть, взрыв мозга для новичка) Но все работает идеально. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко думаю в скором времени всё будете понимать подобное. Достаточно простое решение на самом деле. В onCreate инициализировали элементы управления. При нажатии кнопки - проверяем заполнены ли поля, если нет выводим сообщение.Метод checkInputIsEmpty вернет TRUE если хотя бы одно из полей, которое оно проверяет, не заполнено

Answer (score 0):

Логика такая: когда пользователь правит любое поле, при каждом символе проверяется все ли поля заполнены, если все поля не пустые значит включаем кнопку.

```
...
import android.text.TextUtils
...

//Создаём слушателя изменения текста
TextWatcher textChangeListener = new TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable p0) {}
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence p0, int p1, int p2, int p3) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence p0, int p1, int p2, int p3) {
        yourButton.setEnabled(isCompletedFields())
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Вешаем слушателя на все поля которые не должны быть пустыми
    damage.addTextChangedListener(textChangeListener)
    fear.addTextChangedListener(textChangeListener)
    health.addTextChangedListener(textChangeListener)
    //итд...
}

/**
    Функция проверяет все ли поля заполнены (в каждом поле минимум 1 символ)
    @return true если все поля заполнены, false в другом случае
*/
public boolean isCompletedFields() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(damage.getText()) 
        && TextUtils.isEmpty(fear.getText()) 
        && TextUtils.isEmpty(health.getText())
        //итд...
        )
        return false
    return true
}
```

*Замечание:*
Рекомендую парсинг полей обрамить в try catch блок, так как любой символ отличный от цифры приведёт к крашу вашего приложения (например пробел)

Comment: Относительно неЦифер -   android:inputType="number"  отлично работает.